# Jobs always stay in STARTING status

Tags: cmd, autosys

I'm pretty new to AutoSys (version 4.5 here) and I've got this problem where the jobs I create always stay in "STARTING" status after execution.

Here's the command, pretty straightforward:

```
DEL /F /Q \\server\share\*.*
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO EndError
EXIT 0
:EndError
EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
```

At first I did not have the `EXIT` statements, so I thought that was it. But alas, it's still doing it. Mind you, I'm FORCE STARTING this specific job to test it. It is part of a box, but I'm not starting the box itself, I want to test the jobs piece by piece.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This usually means that your job cannot connect to the AutoSys service on a machine where job should be started. Restart or configure service (agent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

job cannot connect to the AutoSys service on a machine where job should be started. Restart or configure service (agent).